# Tossing a coin with time evolving bias

Tags: probability, martingales, random-walk

Consider the following random process starting at time $t = 1$ with a coin such that $\Pr(\text{Heads}) = p_1$. The bias of the coin, $p_t$, evolves with time as follows for $t \geq 1$:

At time $t$, the coin is tossed (it has $\Pr(\text{Heads}) = p_t$). Let $X_t$ denote the outcome of the toss.
\begin{align}
p_{t+1} = \begin{cases} \max\{p_t - \Delta_1, 0\} & \text{ if } X_t = \text{Heads}, \\ 
\min\{p_t + \Delta_2, 1\} & \text{ if } X_t = \text{Tails},\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $0 < \Delta_1 < \Delta_2$ are some small known constants. Thus, the bias of the coin evolves with time such that it always attempts to make the coin a fair one based on the observed outcome of a toss.

I am interested in bounding the following expression: $\displaystyle \Pr\left( \bigcup_{t = 1}^T \{p_t < \epsilon\} \right)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. The value of $T$ is known and $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ are small constants, roughly $O(1/T)$, so that the $p_t$ does not tend to saturate to extreme values often.

Intuitively, this probability should be small because of the "corrective" nature of the underlying random process. However, I am unable to obtain an elegant upper bound on the same. The union bound is resulting in a very weak bound. I have also tried some Martingale based approaches but haven't been to find a concrete answer.

Any hints or references will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I’ve been working for a few years on first-return times in a very similar model (with$\Delta_1=\Delta_2$) for a few years, on and off, in my nonexistent spare time. Mine is framed as a biased random walk but it’s the same thing. You need some constraints on $\Delta$ and the initial condition to ensure that $p$ stays between zero and one. Then you can get some expressions involving hypergeometric functions for the z-transform of $\Pr(p_t=x)$. But you are interested in a special case (“near the endpoints” in my random walk) where you might find a simple approximation.

Comment: @sasquires Thanks for your reply. So this is a simplified version of the problem I am working on. In the original one, the constraints ensure that $p_t$ stays in $[0,1]$. Yeah I also tried using the MGF of $p_t$ but in that case I have to end up using the union bound which is too weak. I didn't really explore the biased random walk angle but I can give it shot. Do you have some specific references/insights that you might have come across and could share here? It might help give me a good starting point. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One clarification: when I mentioned Fourier transforms and z-transforms above, then this is what you would do if the problem was not bounded in space.  For this particular problem it's easier to think of these as generating functions, as I did in my answer below.  (But of course these are basically different representations of the same thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long to be a comment, and it will necessarily be incomplete, but I'll start writing up some of what I know whenever I get a chance.  (I apologize in advance that I'll edit this post a few times, but I won't have a chance to write it all in one sitting.)

In terms of references, I had a hard time finding anyone else who had studied this problem, because the literature uses different terminology than I would have.  I searched for random walks, biased coin tosses, avalanche processes, and branching processes.  But the main results in this field are from Karlin and McGregor studying "birth-death processes" in the 1950s.

They study a case where the probability of births/deaths is linearly biased, which is similar to our problem, but I don't think it's exactly the same, because the population is not bounded from above.  It's been a long time since I read these papers, so I could have misremembered something.  The best short summary that I remember reading is in the following book, under the topic "random walk polynomials":  *Recurrence Relations, Continued Fractions and Orthogonal Polynomials* by Richard Askey and Mourad Ismail.

As you've already seen and I will make explicit below, the problem is equivalent to a random walk where the probability of moving left/right is linearly biased with respect to the current position.  (I have jokingly called this "a drunkard in a valley," since the drunkard is more likely to move downhill toward the center of the valley.)

There are a number of famous results that apply to random walks with arbitrary move coefficients.  For example, there is a series representation due to Touchard.  There is also an extremely easy way to represent the time generating function of the first-return time as a continued fraction, and there is a method for handling such continued fractions due to Flajolet from around 1990.  But I wasn't able to use any of these to get something useful out of the problem.  I was successful using the poor physicist's standard trick of applying transforms.  I suspect that I don't have enough to solve your problem but definitely enough to get started.

Most of my existing results are in my office, where I can't access them right now because of the pandemic.  But I have enough at home that I should be able to give the really basic results.

My formulation of the problem is that there is a random walk with position $X(t)$ where the probability of moving left/right when at position $x$ is
$$ \begin{align} \ell_x &= 1 - \frac{x}{N} \\ r_x &= \frac{x}{N} \end{align} $$
where $N$ is a positive integer.

Let $p_{x,t}^s$ be the probability that $X(t)=x$ given that $X(0)=s$ (the "start" position).  Then $p_{x,t}^s$ satisfies
$$ p_{x,t}^s = (1 - \delta_{x,0}) r_{x-1} p_{x-1,t-1}^s + (1 - \delta_{x,N}) \ell_{x+1} p_{x+1,t-1}^s + \delta_{x,s} \delta_{t,0} $$
where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.  The first term represents a walk moving right from $x-1$ to $x$.  The second is a walk moving left from $x+1$ to $x$.  The third is the initial condition.

Let $P_x^s(z)$ be the generating function of $P_{x,t}^s$ with respect to $t$, i.e.,
$$ P_x^s(z) = \sum_{t=0}^\infty p_{x,t}^s z^t $$
Then one can show from the time-evolution equation of $p$ that
$$ P_x^s(z) = (1 - \delta_{x,0}) z r_{x-1} P_{x-1}^s(z) + (1 - \delta_{x,N}) z \ell_{x+1} P_{x+1}^s(z) $$
Now let $P^s(u, z)$ be the generating function of $P^s(z)$ with respect to $x$, i.e.
$$ P^s(u, z) = \sum_{x=0}^N P_x^s(z) u^x $$
The time-evolution equation becomes a differential equation in $P^s(u,z)$ in $u$:
$$ \frac{z}{N} (u^2 - 1) \frac{dP^s}{du} + (1 - uz) P^s = u^s $$

This is a linear first-order inhomogeneous differential equation, so the solution is straightforward.  The homogeneous part has solution
$$ \begin{align}
H(u, z) &= \exp\left( \frac{N}{z} \int \frac{1 - uz}{1 - u^2} du \right) \\
        &= C_s(z) (1 - u)^{-\alpha(z)} (1 + u)^{\beta(z)}
\end{align} $$
where $\alpha(z) = \frac{N}{2z}(1-z)$ and $\beta(z) = \frac{N}{2z}(1+z)$.  $C_s(z)$ is an integration constant that can depend on $z$ since the integration is with respect to $u$.  The integral is easy (just decompose into partial fractions).

The inhomogeneous part can be written as an integral in the usual way.  The closed form solution is an Appell $F_1$ function.  (The full expression is in my office notes.)  But in many applications, including mine but possibly not yours, there is one really important thing to observe.  The inhomogeneous solution must be $O(u^{s+1})$.  You can see this by writing the solution $P^s(u, z) = u^{s+1} f(u, z)$ and then show that $f(0, z)$ is a constant.

This has a hugely important corollary: For $x \le s$, *the homogeneous part is the entire solution*.  I'll use this below.  (Everything below is based on the assumption that $x \le s$.)  Moreover, if you need to consider $x > s$, then you can note that the original problem has a symmetry where the substitutions $x \to N - x$ and $s \to N - s$ do not affect the probabilities.  So you can essentially figure out quite a lot about the probabilities without ever calculating the inhomogeneous solution.

*On the other hand,* there is still $C_s(z)$.  There isn't an obvious boundary condition to determine $C_s(z)$ without the full inhomogeneous solution.  (For example, we know that $P^s(1,1)=\frac{1}{1-z}$, but this involves terms where $x>s$.)  It turns out that $C_s(z)$ is closely related to the inhomogeneous solution.  I believe that the relationship is something like $C_s(z)=-I_s(1,z)$, where $I_s(u,z)$ is the inhomogeneous solution.  This is based off of my memory, but I think that there is a simple argument to show this based on requiring $I_s(u,z)$ to be well-behaved near $u=1$.  This means that you can derive a lot of information about the *ratios* of probabilities at different values of $x$, but you can't get the absolute probabilities unless you solve the inhomogeneous problem.

With all this in mind, we can start inverting the generating functions.
The series for $H(u,z)$ in $u$ is
$$ \begin{align}
H(u,z) &= C_s(z) \sum(1 - u)^{-\alpha(z)} (1 + u)^{\beta(z)} \\
       &= C_s(z) \sum_{j,k} (-1)^j \binom{-\alpha}{j} \binom{\beta}{k} u^{j+k} \\
       &= C_s(z) \sum_x u^x \sum_j (-1)^j \binom{-\alpha}{j} \binom{\beta}{x-j} \\
       &= C_s(z) \sum_x u^x \binom{\beta}{x} {_2}F_1\left(\begin{matrix} \alpha, -x \\ \beta - x + 1 \end{matrix}; -1 \right)
\end{align} $$
where ${_2}F_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function.  So for $x \le s$ then we have
$$ P^s_x(z) = C_s(z) \binom{\beta}{x} {_2}F_1\left(\begin{matrix} \alpha, -x \\ \beta - x + 1 \end{matrix}; -1 \right) $$

This may be the end of the results that I have that are useful to you.  I'm not really sure.  I'm happy to keep discussing here when you have thought about it.  I am mainly interested in deriving simple numerical approximations for the first-passage time to $x=s-1$, which is related to the ratio $P^s_s(z)/P^s_{s-1}(z)$.  If this is useful I can probably provide some more information.  But you may need absolute probabilities near $x=0$ or $x=N$, which is something I haven't devoted a lot of time to thinking about this.

One more piece of advice.  The hypergeometric representation above is hard to invert, but it is very versatile and you can extract a lot of information from it.  (There are a bunch of equivalent hypergeometric representations using Euler and Pfaff transforms, and of course there are also integral representations.)  And there are other approaches to the same problem, like the orthogonal polynomial representation of Karlin and McGregor mentioned above, that are closely related.

*Disclaimer:* All of the above is based on very messy notes where I had re-derived some of the main expressions at home, and there may be typos, so some of it may need fixing.  Please let me know if you find errors.

Comment: (If this wasn’t clear, I am going to dig up my notes and post more. But I have a three year old that keeps me busy nonstop, and our work schedule is crazy due to the pandemic, so it will come in bits and pieces when I get time over the next few days.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references. I will go through them and see if I get some ideas from there and also look into the z-transform method again. I should hopefully get some leads from there. Also whenever it is comfortable for you (there is no rush at all, these suggestions should keep me occupied for a while) can you please share the basic results you have? Would be helpful to have something to check against especially if I get stuck again. Once again, thank you so much for your time. I understand these few months have been challenging and I really appreciate you taking out time for this. :)

Comment: That is an amazingly detailed answer! Thank you so much for taking out the time for writing that up. It would definitely be very helpful. It will take me a while to absorb all this and adapt this to my situation (especially I have limited experience with generating functions and hypergeometric functions). I will get back to you once I have made some progress or if I have some more questions. Thank you so much once again for sharing this with me! :)

Comment: You’re welcome. For my problem, this is just the very beginning. I’m using this to understand finite-size effects in certain avalanche processes, and I’ve been planning on writing a paper about this for years now, basically since I finished grad school, but I haven’t found the time. I am mostly just glad that someone is interested in the same model, though presumably for different reasons.

Comment: Oh that's interesting! And I definitely understand that part of not being able to get time to work on a pet problem. In my case, I am working on a totally different problem and one of the lemmas involves bounding that probability for slightly complicated variant of the problem I posted. Now after reading your answer, it seems I've opened a Pandora's box. It seems like a very interesting problem in its own right. I'm glad I posted this on MSE and got your insights. There is no way I'd worked this out. I hope you get around to finally publish that paper! Definitely looking forward to it!